# Limit size using Quota per file for a user

Tags: linux, centos, user-management, quota

I am working on a linux machine . i have a user name dave. i want to implement quota on /home/dave . that dave could not create more than 2 MB file in this main directory. user can create any sub directory contain so many files but size of each file should not more than 2 MB. Is it possible ? if yes then how ?

Comment: You can edit /etc/security/limit.conf for desired file size limit per user or group.

Comment: ...although note that limits set via this mechanism aren't tied to the filesystem (that is, they apply anywhere, not just under `/home/dave`, which may or may not be what you want).